# More on rotation matrices: a basis for $SO(3)$?

Tags: lie-groups

Consider the group $SO(3)$. The rotation around the $x$-axis is represented by the matrix

$$R_x = \left ( \begin{array}{ ccc }
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \Theta & - \sin \Theta \\
0 & \sin \Theta & \cos \Theta
\end{array}\right )
$$

Similarly, for [the rotations around the other axes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). It is very easy to verify that these three are linearly independent.

I wanted to show that they form a basis for $SO(3)$. But this is where I got stuck. The idea should be to consider an arbitrary rotation and then show that it is a linear combination of these $3$ matrices. But I don't know what a generic rotation matrix looks like. So maybe there is a different way of showing this or maybe it is even false.

Please can someone help me?

Comment: $SO(3)$ is not a group under addition, so you're not going to get very far with showing something is a basis in the sense of linear algebra. The relevant notion is of a generating set of a group.

Comment: Consider the action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$.

Comment: @curious But it is a group under multiplication. Why does it matter what we call the group operation?

Comment: Uhm, maybe I get it. What we call addition would be linear with scalar multiplcation but multiplication is not linear with scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basis is the wrong word. However, you are correct; an oriented (orthogonal) basis can be rotated to the standard $x,y,z$ directions in no more than 3 standard rotations. One to put the $x$ vector in the $xz$ plane. a second rotation to send it to the positive $x$ axis. One final rotation in the $yz$ plane to take those vectors to their proper positions.